# Can WPF UI elements be in the foreground of UWP elements included via Visual Layer Compositor?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, uwp

In short terms: I would like to use some elements from UWP in my WPF application. My issue is that the UWP elements always appear on top of all my other WPF UI elements (e.g. buttons, rectangles,...).

I cannot share the original example, but I'm currently trying to get it working with the following example: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows.UI.Composition-Win32-Samples/tree/master/dotnet/WPF/HelloComposition

In this example there is the "CompositionHostControl".
Just to prove that I can put a WPF UI control in front of it I added a rectangle:

```
        <local:CompositionHostControl x:Name="CompositionHostControl1"
                                      Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                      Width="600" Height="500"
                                      BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="3" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
        
        <Rectangle Fill="Aqua" Width="200" Height="200" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Panel.ZIndex="2" />
```

Based on my understanding of "Panel.ZIndex" the rectangle should be infront (=top most) of the CompositionHostControl.

However, this does not work. The rectangle is always rendered behind the CompositionHostControl.

I also looked into the 'CompositionHostControl.xaml.cs' but could not find anything that sets this control to be topmost.

In the 'CompositionHost.cs' I changed line 119 from

```
interop.CreateDesktopWindowTarget(hwndHost, true, out raw);
```

to

```
interop.CreateDesktopWindowTarget(hwndHost, false, out raw);
```

since the second parameter has the name 'isTopmost'. However, that also had no effect.

I had a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/composition/visual-layer and to me it looks like it should be possible to change the Z order, but I did not find out how to do it.

I also had a look at https://mtaulty.com/2015/12/17/m_15996/ where it more or less clearly says "I can also combine some or all of 1-4 above in order to allow the separate technologies to play to their strengths – e.g. I might have some Direct3D game sitting underneath a set of game controls provided by a XAML layer."

Last but not least, I'm in general aware of the Air Space problem: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.0/aa970688(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN
However, my understanding was that this would not be the case since everything is based on the visual layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is still a matter of [airspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/technology-regions-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), this limitation comes from mixing different technologies at the window manager level, not a WPF implementation decision.

CompositionHostControl is essentially a Win32 child window and you cannot draw WPF content on top of it.

It is recommended to use `SetWindowRgn` to limit the drawing of some areas. For example, if you want to add a WPF Rectangle above, you can use `CombineRgn` to get a region with a rectangular hole, so that the content of WPF can be displayed.

```
 protected override HandleRef BuildWindowCore(HandleRef hwndParent)
 {
     // Create Window
     hwndHost = IntPtr.Zero;
     hwndHost = CreateWindowEx(0, "static", "Win32Window",
                               WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE ,
                               0, 0,
                               hostWidth, hostHeight,
                               hwndParent.Handle,
                               (IntPtr)HOST_ID,
                               IntPtr.Zero,
                               0);

     // Create Dispatcher Queue
     dispatcherQueue = InitializeCoreDispatcher();

     // Build Composition Tree of content
     InitComposition(hwndHost);

     var hrgn = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, hostWidth, hostHeight);
     var wpfRgn = CreateRectRgn(300, 300, 200, 200);
     var region = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, 0, 0);
     CombineRgn(region, hrgn, wpfRgn, RGN_DIFF);  //RGN_DIFF=4

     int regionType = SetWindowRgn(hwndHost, region, true);

     return new HandleRef(this, hwndHost);
 }
```

Comment: Junjie, thank you so much for this fast and on point answer!

One solution I may look into now are "Adorner" as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30872931/how-can-i-add-a-wpf-overlay-over-an-external-win32-applications-window

That would mean one Window showing the UWP stuff and on top of that I have the WPF adorner window. Is that a reallistic path or do the same issues appear?

Comment: I read the information you shared, and it seems possible, but I haven't tried it yet, its safety is unknown. it may take some time to transplant, good luck to you!

Comment: I tried the HwndAdorner mentioned in the other post and it does work for .NET 4.8. With .NET 6+ it does not work reliably.